# Android keep showing old image after uploading new profile image

Tags: android

In my Android application, users can upload their profile images. It successfully uploaded new image on server, but it still showing old image in application. Of course, I reloaded image via HTTP in the application, but it still showing old image.

After I turn off the application and start again, it shows uploaded image in the Android application. So, I was thinking that it should be a cache problem like website. I tried to delete cache after uploading image, but it still didn't work.

I've searched all over to fix this problem, but I failed to find the solution.

Does the new images save in Android memory? Anyone have an idea? Thank you.

**Here is the codes.**

```
public static void download(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    Bitmap cachedImage = mImageCache.get(url);


    if(cachedImage != null)
    {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(cachedImage);
    }
    else if(cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView))
    {
        mImageCache.clear();

        ImageDownloaderTask task = new ImageDownloaderTask(url, imageView);
        DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
        task.execute(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ate you re-setting the image to wherever it is shown?

Comment: called re-setting image method in onresume()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reload Image when server uploading completes and application come back to previous activity so @Ravind was right, you have to reset ImageView in onResume(),

```
imageView.setImage(yourImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the http client your application is using has options to disable caching.

If you're using `HttpURLConnection` see this blog post - http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

> In Ice Cream Sandwich, we are adding a response cache. With the cache installed, HTTP requests will be satisfied in one of three ways:
>
> Fully cached responses are served directly from local storage. Because no network connection needs to be made such responses are available immediately.
>
> Conditionally cached responses must have their freshness validated by the webserver. The client sends a request like “Give me /foo.png if it changed since yesterday” and the server replies with either the updated content or a 304 Not Modified status. If the content is unchanged it will not be downloaded!
>
> Uncached responses are served from the web. These responses will get stored in the response cache for later.

Answer (score 0):

Add this call to your HTTP:

```
.enableHttpResponseCache
```